# Find unassociate public IP Azure

Tags: azure, resources, azure-resource-graph

I'm tryig to find unassociate public IP in my Azure subscription with Azure resource graph explorer.
I was able to find for a NSG but I can't do the same thing with public IP.
Is somebody has an idea about the Query that I can use ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use that snippet. It is really worth learning KustoQL, as it is extremly useful to find resources or log entries.

```
resources
| where type == "microsoft.network/publicipaddresses"
| where isempty(properties.ipConfiguration)
```